# Does a C++11 range-based for loop condition get evaluated every cycle?

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, c++11, foreach

```
for(auto& entity : memoryManager.getItems()) entity->update(mFrameTime);
```

If memoryManager contains 1000 items, does `memoryManager.getItems()` get called 1000 times or only one at the beginning of the loop?

Does the compiler run any optimization with -O2 (or -O3)?

(`memoryManager.getItems()` returns a `std::vector<Entity*>&`)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It is only evaluated once. The standard defines a range-based `for` statement as equivalent to:

```
{
    auto && __range = range-init;
    for ( auto __begin = begin-expr, __end = end-expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
        for-range-declaration = *__begin;
        statement
    }
}
```

where `range-init` is the expression (surrounded by parentheses) or braced-init-list after the `:`

Comment: Almost. Where right of the `:` is an expression, `range-init` is that expression enclosed in parentheses. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Indeed. And, in case anyone cares why that matters, "this ensures that a top-level comma operator cannot be reinterpreted as a delimiter between init-declarators in the declaration of `__range`."

Comment: while `range-init` is evaulated once, `++__begin` will be evaluted each loop so that if the underlying data structure is changed, values that were not in the underlying data structure when `range-init` was evaulated may be assigned to the `for-range-declaration`, including resultant undefined behavior (e.g. invalidated itertors).  Just clarifying that "evaulated once" does not equate to all values safely being generated at that time.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum thanks, this is a very important clarification.