# C++11 range-based for loop on temp object

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

Is it legal to write something like the following? In case of positive answer would you do that?

```
vector<int> create_vector() { vector<int> v; ... return v;}

for ( auto i : create_vector() ) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: It seems this question has already been asked in a slightly different formulation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766020/does-a-c11-foreach-loop-condition-get-evaluated-every-cycle?lq=1 and the answer appears to be yes.

Comment: Good find, voted to close as a dupe of that. And yes, this is fine.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it throws a bunch of error for me ? Is it even a valid syntax ? `vector<int> create_vector() { vector<int> v;  return v;};` ?

Comment: @POW extra semicolon at the end of the inline function implementation?